# wget from ftp: supress default page creation

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download subfolder from **ftp**. There are only data files.
I'm using: `wget -nH -np --cut-dirs=5 -r http://sss.com/1/2/3/4/5`

Unfortunately wget creates one additional file: index.html
which contains a list of downloaded files.

I found an argument to rename it. But didn't find anything to not allow wget its creation at all. I just need a copy of ftp's subfolder without any additional files.

Am I missed something? Or `rm index.html` is only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you need to avoid index.html download.
Then you need this (from `wget` man page):

```
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
       accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *,
       ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be
       treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.  In this case, you have
       to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from
       expanding it, like in -A "*.mp3" or -A '*.mp3'.
```

So you have to add -R index.html and it will instruct `wget` to exclude index.html from list of files to download.

Comment: I thought index.html is generated locally as there is no such file on ftp. Perhaps ftp server sends it additionally of wget gets it via http request. Anyway, `-R index.html` seems help.